# Kubernetes NGINX-ingress returns 404

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I'm a k8s newbie and I am trying to expose a port from the cluster into the local network.
I've tried to do it with metallb config layer2 + load balancer controller and this runs ok.

I have set up a 3-node environment with kubespray.
((192.168.0.1[5,6,7]))

However, I'm trying to expose an api with NodePort and NGINX-Ingress. The nodeport api service is running ok (i can make successfull requests via NODE_IP:NODE_nodeport). But if I try this ingress configuration it justs keeps telling me "connection refused":

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-api
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "k8s.customhostname.com" # solves to 192.168.0.17 which has a running pod with the api.
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /test
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: svc-api
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Then i check the services:

```
Name:              svc-smouapimapes
Namespace:         smouapi
Labels:            app=apimapes
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=apimapes
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.233.26.225
Port:              springboot  8080/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         10.233.90.4:8080,10.233.92.8:8080
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

And then check the ingress:

```
Name:             ingress-smouapimapes
Namespace:        smouapi
Address:          192.168.0.17
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host                     Path  Backends
  ----                     ----  --------
  k8s.domain.com
                           /test   svc-domain:8080   10.233.90.4:8080,10.233.92.8:8080)
Annotations:               nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: false
Events:                    <none>
```

Whenever i call :

```
curl -I http://k8s.domain.com/test
# CONNECTION REFUSED
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enin, you should configure the domain `k8s.nexusgeografics.com` to be resolved to the ip that providing the nginx-ingress service, thus, you can access your service through nginx-ingress.

Comment: Hi Kun Li, the DNS of my network already points to that IP addres that nginx-ingress provided (192.168.0.17). But Still got the same "connection refused error"...

Comment: from your post: `solves to 192.168.0.17 which has a running pod with the api`, I don't think it's the same pod that running nginx-ingress.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following in the Nginx config ingress-smouapimapes.
Add annotation :

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
```

And instead of this  `path: /test`  add  `path: /test(/|$)(.*)`

Comment: you are definitely missing something. Try putting path as " / " in ingress . Then debug the issue step by step. Sometimes apis are available on a particular path such as "/v1"

Comment: Thanks @avadhut007, it worked. If you can explain a bit more of what /$2 means it would be helpful. Believe me, I spent more than a day trying to figure out whats wrong.

Comment: path: /test(/|$)(.*)
$1 will have values from first parenthesis().. $2 will have values from second parenthesis()